# Winform progress bar only updating when process is finished (C#, Python)

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, progress-bar

Using a C# Winform as GUI to run my Python script in the background. Currently am applying a backgroundworker to handle it in another thread and keep the GUI responsive; however, the progress bar only seems to update when the process is finished. Stays at Value=0 and then changes to Value=100 once the process terminates; would much prefer have it increase as python executes the background process so I know it's still alive and working..
My understanding is that blocking should not be occurring because the backgroundworker is moving the process to a separate thread, so I'm not too sure what could be stopping it from updating.
Here's the relevant sections of my C# code:

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged); 
        }
----
        private void button_test2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  // this is the active button
        {
            if (backgroundWorker1.IsBusy != true)
            {
                backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();

            }
        }
----
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
               
            if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                //break;
            }
            else
            {
                // Cutting out some stuff here for brevity. Just assigns arg1-4 based on inputs from the GUI, nothing crazy

                // Python script to run
                process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\blablabla\python.exe";
                string script = @"C:\paths\pythonscriptgoeshere.py";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \"{arg1}\" \"{arg2}\" \"{arg3}\" \"{arg4}\"";

                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.Start();

                while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    bool ItsAnInt = Int32.TryParse(process.StandardOutput.ReadLine(),out int PyOutput);
                    if (ItsAnInt)  // I know this part is ugly lol - just making sure only numbers/percentages are being passed
                    {
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(PyOutput);  
                        // PyOut is just a percentage (0-100) of how many iterations it has completed out of the total
                    }
      
                }

                //string stderrx = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                //string stdoutx = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                //MessageBox.Show($"Output: {stdoutx}\nError: {stderrx}");
            }
---
        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }
```

Not quite sure why the progressbar1.Value isn't being updated from `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged` since it seems to be called while the process is actively running. Anyway, sorry for the long post and thanks for any help.
Cheers!

**EDIT:** Thank you @Jimi for helping me figure this out in the comments. The issue was that the UI was flooded with request since the test data set I was using was computed faster than the progressbar could update so it essentially didn't get a chance to breathe and catch up. Solution was to add in a Thread.Sleep(1) every handful of iterations to let it update.

**EDIT 2:** The plot thickens! Turns out that the progress bar would give me updates like I wanted, but wouldn't start the processes of updating until the background process was already done. Turns out what I needed to do was make a **second background worker** as well as an **external python script** that would read outputs and then report them to the bar. Not the best solution I'm sure but it seemed to do the trick for me :-)

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on the loop where you ReadLine, does it hang until finished, or does it read and then loop.

Comment: @Neil Reads and then loops. That whole loop there is also not very important from what I can tell. More of an artifact of something I never got around to adding. Got rid of it and just had to read PyOut and do the report progress without that loop/ItsAnInt check and I'm getting the same output as before

Comment: Add `Console.WriteLine(PyOutput);` inside that loop and check how many times it actually writes.

Comment: @Jimi Had it give me a MessageBox.Show() for each PyOutput and it did give me N boxes for all N files it was passing. Oddly enough though, when I was prompted for the MessageBox, the progress bar moved up to match the most recent box's output. Interesting! Albeit I had to close each one to get the next so it's still...bad... but I suppose things are not as bad as I thought they were haha

Comment: So, the output is so fast that you only can see the last value. Note that the ProgressBar animation has a timed delay both at the start and the end of its progress update.  If your procedure is faster than the animation or if you *overload* the UI, by flooding it, you see nothing but the last update in any case; when the UI has actually the chance to update itself.

Comment: You can probably see it better if you add `Thread.Sleep(1);` to the loop, inside the `if` condition (this will slow down the loop quite a bit, though).

Comment: @Jimi yeah that seemed to be the issue. Giving it a Thread.Sleep(1) every 20 iterations or so seemed to do the trick. Thank you so much!